# Limited memory and CPU in the apache virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, centos6, cpu-usage

How can I limit the memory and CPU of each virtualhost on a apache running on CentOS?

Comment: Have you tried RLimitCPU, RLimitMEM, and RLimitNPROC?

Comment: I did not know these parameters. I have just set up and will monitor. Return soon with the result. Thank you.